# Probability density function / maximum likelihood for correlating sequence

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

I have a stream that contains two consecutive identical sequences, each of length $N$. These sequences have a ideal autocorrelation property. So I want to have the probability density function over $2N$ samples. So before the sequences, the pdf $f(x)$ for the examined vector $[x_1,\ldots,x_{2N}]$ is just a multiplikation of statistically independent values 
$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2N})=\prod_{k=1}^{2N} f(x_k).$$

For the case of the correlating values of the consecutive identical sequences: How can it be simplyfied (since they are not statistically independent anymore)?
$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2N}) = ?$$

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2N})=f(x_1)f(x_2|x_1)f(x_3|x_2,x_1)\ldots f(x_{2N}|x_{2N-1},x_{2N-2},\ldots,x_2,x_1)$